# How can I convert a UV map into a mesh?

Tags: mesh, uv, edit-mode

Blender 2.7 is going to support sewing. It makes sense to be able to unwrap an object (clothes) in to a 2d pattern, orientate the 2d panels around the body and then 'sew' it back together to simulate how the pattern fits.

Is it currently possible to convert a UV map in to a mesh?

Comment: Can you explain more about how you would use this? for example. would a tool to split edges in the mesh based on UV seams be useful? - perhaps a way to apply the UV's as a shape key?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14074/599

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there aren't tools to do this right at the moment, but this is a fairly simple operation. Internally the exporting UV's layout to PNG does this. its just hidden from the user and the mesh is removed immediately afterwards.

Comment: Nice, this should be added to the UVs menu as *Convert to mesh*

Comment: @CoDEmanX I've created a script here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14074/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-meshs-uvs-into-a-second-mesh-using-a-script/14076#14076